# Swagger codegen option to don't generate hashCode() and equals()

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

The following refers to the generation of the Spring boot server stubs with swagger codegen (-l spring).

Is there any option for Swagger codegen binary (current: v2.3.1) to generate the dto models without the hashCode() and equals() methods?

I did not found any options in the config-help. I want the generated dto models to extend an abstract class where the hashCode() and equals() methods are already declared and therefore shouldn't be overwritten in the generated model classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to customize the mustache templates (by removing those lines related to hashCode(), equals()) and use the `-t` option when generating the spring boot server stubs.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. And here the modification is explained: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#modifying-the-client-library-format

Comment: Nice. If you don't mind, please contact me via my email address in https://github.com/wing328/ as I've some questions about your experience using the generator. Thanks.